# Convergence of $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\:\frac{\left(\ln n\right)^{10}}{n^{1.1}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Determine whether this is convergent or divergent.
$$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\:\frac{\left(\ln n\right)^{10}}{n^{1.1}}$$

I tried comparing it with a harmonic sum to see if I can prove convergence, but I can't seem to find a proper answer. I really have a hard time dealing with sums that you need to use the comparison test with.

Comment: We don't really want to start at $n=0$. Do a Limit Comparison with $\sum_1^\infty \frac{1}{n^{1.05}}$.

Comment: You're right, should start at 1. If I do a limit comparison with the series you just mentioned wouldn't that yield me infinity?

Comment: In the long run the terms of your series are less than the terms of the series I proposed, That series converges, so your series converges.

Comment: How are they less? Aren't the terms in my series always going to be $\gt$ the terms in the proposed series?

Comment: In the long run $n^{0.05}$ is greater than any power of a logarithm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There exists $N$ such that for $n > N$,
$$
\ln n < n^{.005}.
$$
Then for $n > N$ we have
$$
\frac{(\ln n)^{10}}{n^{1.1}}
< \frac{n^{.05}}{n^{1.1}}
= \frac{1}{n^{1.05}}.
$$
Since $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^{1.05}}$ converges, this sum converges by the comparison test.

Answer (score 1):

This is  a series with positive terms. Furthermore, for any $\alpha>0$, $(\ln n)^\alpha=o(n^{0.05})$, say. Hence 
$$\frac{\ln^\alpha n}{n^{1.1}}=o\biggl(\frac1{n^{1.05}}\biggl),$$
which converges.

Comment: Not familiar with the $o$ notation(we haven't studied it yet) so I don't think I should be using that :(

Comment: Then you can prove the function $\dfrac{\ln^{10} x}{x^{0.05}}$ is bounded on $[1,+\infty)$.

Comment: @MikhaelM $f$ being little-$o$ of $g$ (written as $f=o(g)$) is simply a convenient way of saying that the function on the right "*dominates*" the function on the left.  I.E. that $f=o(g)\Leftrightarrow \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{f(n)}{g(n)}=0 \Leftrightarrow f\prec g$